# Function not working correctly, x != (y or z)

Tags: python, variables

This is for a school project. The if statement (if jantina != ("L" or "P"): ) only acts true when the input is "L" when I use "or", but when I use "and", it only acts true for "P". I'm trying to make it so that when either string is inputted, it acts as true. I've tried asking other people I know but nothing seems to work. Will edit if any more information is needed, thanks in advance!

```
def kalkulatorKalori():
  print("1. Sedentari: Anda jarang melakukan aktiviti senaman, hanya yang melibatkan aktiviti seharian")
  print("2. Moderasi: Anda melakukan aktiviti senaman lebih kurang 2-5 kali seminggu")
  print("3. Aktif: Anda melakukan aktiviti senaman 6-7 kali seminggu")
  jantina = input(str("Masukkan jantina anda [L/P]: "))
  if jantina != ("L" or "P"):
    print("Itu bukan pilihan yang dibenarkan.")
    sleep(3)
    system("clear")
    kalkulatorKalori()
  umur = input(str("Masukkan umur anda: "))
  if int(umur) < 13:
    print("Itu bukan pilihan yang dibenarkan.")
    sleep(3)
    system("clear")
    kalkulatorKalori()
  activity = input(str("Masukkan kadar keaktifan anda [1-3]: "))
  if activity == "3":
    keaktifan = 3
  elif activity == "2":
    keaktifan = 2
  elif activity == "1":
    keaktifan = 1
  else:
    print("Pilihan anda perlulah [1-3]")
    sleep(3)
    system("clear")
    kalkulatorKalori()
  return keaktifan, jantina, umur
```

Comment: `or` doesn't work that way.  use `if jantina not in ("L", "P"):`

Comment: Right.  `("L" or "P")` is a boolean expression that, under Python's rules, has the value `"L"`.  Note that `if jantina not in "LP":` works just as well.